# How to capture Clientside random bugs?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, performance-testing

I have React based app it shows random Clientside bugs which cause app crash. How to capture error if someone face or app crashes.

Comment: error boundary? https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html then there are tools like sentry to see the actual errors your clients get https://sentry.io/welcome/

Comment: @azium sometime I face issue like some div is undefined and i have used in my code did error boundries can catch that???

Comment: it might, it kind of depends on where your code is executing. there's also `window.onerror`

Comment: @azium in react code I have mention div, sometime when these div is undefined then it crash my app, does react error boundaries can catch those error????

Comment: can you update your question with the code you're talking about? I'm not sure I understand